# Can't loop over a json list in p5

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

First question ever here and a total newbie one.

I'm trying to write a script in .p5 that load a .json file and print out all the results for a given category. If I call one specific entry it prints out the result but I didn't figure out why it didn't print when a try doing a loop.

Like this:

```
var data;

function preload() {
    data = loadJSON("assets/data-test.json");
}

function setup() {

    noCanvas();

    var cdu = data.cdu;
    var qtde = data.qtde;
    var autor = data.autor;
    var titulo = data.titulo;
    var sub_titulo = data.sub_titulo;
    var isbn = data.isbn;
    var publicacao = data.publicacao;

    for (var i = 0; i < cdu.length; i++) {
        createElement("h1",data[i].cdu);
    }

}
```

My .json file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "cdu": "53 F363f  Ac.1028543",
    "qtde": 3,
    "autor": "FERNANDES, C. E. de M.",
    "titulo": "Fundamentos de física para geociências.",
    "sub_titulo": "",
    "isbn": "ISBN 9788571931596.",
    "publicacao": "Rio de Janeiro:  Intercincia,  2007."
  },
  {
    "cdu": "37(81) F137s  Ac.1019442",
    "qtde": 1,
    "autor": "BOHN, Hilario Inacio;  SOUZA, Osmar de (Org.).",
    "titulo": "Faces do saber:",
    "sub_titulo": "desafios à educaáão do futuro.",
    "isbn": "ISBN 9788574741109.",
    "publicacao": "Florianópolis:  Insular,  [2002?]."
  },
  {
    "cdu": "001 A474f  Ac.262110",
    "qtde": 8,
    "autor": "ALVES, Rubem.",
    "titulo": "Filosofia da cincia:",
    "sub_titulo": "Introdução ao jogo e suas regras.",
    "isbn": "ISBN 97588585470531.",
    "publicacao": "São Paulo:  Ars Poetica,  1996."
  }
]
```

Can someone give me some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to loop `data.cdu` but `data` is an array.

Comment: you should tag p5.js, not p5, you'll get more answers

Comment: @HReynaud Thanks! I'll do this next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "cdu": "53 F363f  Ac.1028543",
    "qtde": 3,
    "autor": "FERNANDES, C. E. de M.",
    "titulo": "Fundamentos de física para geociências.",
    "sub_titulo": "",
    "isbn": "ISBN 9788571931596.",
    "publicacao": "Rio de Janeiro:  Intercincia,  2007."
  },
  {
    "cdu": "37(81) F137s  Ac.1019442",
    "qtde": 1,
    "autor": "BOHN, Hilario Inacio;  SOUZA, Osmar de (Org.).",
    "titulo": "Faces do saber:",
    "sub_titulo": "desafios à educaáão do futuro.",
    "isbn": "ISBN 9788574741109.",
    "publicacao": "Florianópolis:  Insular,  [2002?]."
  },
  {
    "cdu": "001 A474f  Ac.262110",
    "qtde": 8,
    "autor": "ALVES, Rubem.",
    "titulo": "Filosofia da cincia:",
    "sub_titulo": "Introdução ao jogo e suas regras.",
    "isbn": "ISBN 97588585470531.",
    "publicacao": "São Paulo:  Ars Poetica,  1996."
  }
]

/***************************************
data in this case is the individual object 
and key is the key in relation to the 
key value pairs

****************************************/
for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
  for(key in data[i]){
    console.log('KEY', key, ' ELEMENT', data[i][key])
  }
}
```

In the above snippet your trying to access element[i] of the key and not the object as the data is an array of objects you need to loop through each object to access the key as seen in the snippet.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the help.